# Repository method findById with underscore Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, repository

In entity class Flights I have fields private City flight_from and private City flight_to and I need repository method to return flights by id of flight_from. I am trying to do like this:

```
List<Flights> findByFlight_toId(Integer id);
```

I have tried findByFlightToId, findByFlight_to_id, findByFlight__toId with double underscore and other, still can't find it. Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

spring-data treats the underscore as a special character, see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions).

Your best solution is to follow the naming conventions and rename your variables `flightTo` and `flightFrom`.